# Is it possible to have example-specific build.rs file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In my library I have few examples -- (normally) each one is represented by a single `x<N>.rs` file living in `examples` directory.

One example uses a `.proto` file -- this file needs to be compiled during build (of said example) and it's generated output is used by example itself.

I've tried this in my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[[example]]
name = "x1"
path = "examples/x1/main.rs"
build = "examples/x1/build.rs"
```

but `build` key gets ignored when I run `cargo build --example x1`

Is it possible to have example-specific `build.rs` file?

If not -- what is the correct way to deal with this situation?

**Edit:** I ended up processing that `.proto` file in crate's `build.rs` (even though it is not required to build that crate) and using artefacts in the example like this:

```
pub mod my_proto {
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/my_proto.rs"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. This [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/7816) explains why, but in a nutshell build scripts are used for whole crate. So you could move your example into separate crate.